# UWP C# UI is not updating when properties inside observable collection containing another observable collection change

Tags: c#, uwp, binding, observable, observablecollection

**Update: Added minimum reproducible example Country name is updating, Hello1, Hello2 ...., however, City temperature is not updating https://github.com/qaftab/Observable**

**Here is my problem:** When I add objects, UI will update. However, when the value of property changes inside Country.CitiesInCountry, UI is not updating. When I asked this question earlier, i was suggested to add BindableBase class which i added.

Therefore, I am looking for help to modify my classes below to update UI (Binding with countries) when any property in the City or Country Object change.

```
public class City : BindableBase
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    /*
           public int Temperature { set; get; }

           public int TEMPERATURE
           {
               get { return Temperature; }
               set
               {
                   Temperature = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("TEMPERATURE");
               }
           }*/
    public int Temperature;
    public int TEMPERATURE
    {
        get => Temperature;
        set => SetProperty(ref Temperature, value);
        
    }

}


public class Country:BindableBase
{
    //public string CountryName { get; set; }
    private string countryName;
    public string CountryName
    {
        get => countryName;
        set => SetProperty(ref countryName, value);
    }



    // public ObservableCollection<City> CitiesInCountry = new ObservableCollection<City>();
    private ObservableCollection<City> CitiesInCountry = new ObservableCollection<City>();
    public ObservableCollection<City> CITIES
    {
        get => CitiesInCountry;
        set => SetProperty(ref CitiesInCountry, value);
    }


}


 [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
    public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Multicast event for property change notifications.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if a property already matches a desired value.  Sets the property and
        /// notifies listeners only when necessary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the property.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="storage">Reference to a property with both getter and setter.</param>
        /// <param name="value">Desired value for the property.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property used to notify listeners.  This
        /// value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers that
        /// support CallerMemberName.</param>
        /// <returns>True if the value was changed, false if the existing value matched the
        /// desired value.</returns>
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies listeners that a property value has changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property used to notify listeners.  This
        /// value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers
        /// that support <see cref="CallerMemberNameAttribute"/>.</param>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't post the same question again. This question was [previously closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64080223) due to it lacking detail, and thus being no different than any other vaguely-stated "my bindings don't work" question. The above is essentially identical, with only the superficial change of using a helper base class for `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you want help, post a _different_ question, with a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem and a clear and detailed explanation of your debugging so far and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: i have added a reproducible example and did not get a clear answer. if i know the answer then why would i create a reproducible example and post it. Can you please take a look at reproducible example?

Comment: Please read [mcve], so that you understand what is required. Pay close attention to the two critical elements of the code example: **minimal** and **complete**. See also [ask] (including the pages linked at the bottom of that article) for more information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: that is minimal. i created it just to post.

Comment: It _might_ be minimal, though frankly it does not appear to be. It most certainly is not **complete**.

Comment: what do i mean it is not complete? i can run it and countryname updates while city temperature doesnot. It contains only three classes. city, country and bindable base. If

Comment: Whatever you're running, there is obviously more to it than the code you've included in your posts here. For a start, you don't have anything here that actually initializes any properties (like the collection), nor is there any XAML at all. And in any case, posting a new question is strictly a violation of community standards. You are expected to _improve the original_, not just keep posting new versions of it until you get it right.

Comment: i have included a github repository. did u look at it?

Comment: https://github.com/qaftab/Observable